# How to run android app on tablet?

Tags: android

I've created an android app that takes a picture when button clicked, which works fine on the Emulator but when I'm trying to run it on my tablet (Novo 10 Hero QuadCore)/actual device it is not working at all. Any idea what must be missing?

Comment: Check the permission in your manifest. Also showing us what code you use to open the camera to take a photo and save it would also help a lot.

Comment: @Razgriz but other programs i've developed are working fine ,i'm not even getting an ERROR message from ADT.

Comment: Check that your application is debuggable by setting the android:debuggable attribute of the <application> element to true.

Comment: @Kanwaljit it is advisable to avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

Comment: ok. For some devices you need to install appropriate drivers, and they may usually be found in the vendor's site.

Comment: could you please post the error message you are getting. You can test on other devices. If you don't have other devices, www.betaglide.com can help test for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure in developer options you have your usb debugging checked

Settings/Developer Options/Usb Debugging

If the options are not available then go to settings tap on "About Phone" 4-5 times and your developer options will be activated

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the layout for tablet. You need to support all the screen size. Please look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html